# How can we run the test cases in Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I am new in android and I am working on unit testing. we don,t know to check or compile the unit cases in android. Please Suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing on android is very simple. Please follow these links to take Google Code labs to practice and implement Unit Testing using Espresso, Junit, Mockito.

Beginner Codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-unit-tests/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0

Advance Codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/#0

Android Official Doc:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html

Step by step guide by Codepath: https://guides.codepath.com/android/UI-Testing-with-Espresso